# Why can't we divide a circumference of a circle with it's diameter perfectly?, In short why is Value of Pi Non Terminating?

Tags: pi

Why can't we divide a **circumference of a circle with its diameter perfectly**?,
In short why is Value of **Pi Non Terminating**?
Does that means we can never find **exact circumference** of any circle?

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_that_%CF%80_is_irrational)

Answer (score 0):

In the math world, we just write $2\pi r$ for the circumference of a circle, and $\pi$ just stays there for the $exact$ answer. We **cannot** find a circle with *exact* circumference without $\pi$, but we cannot draw a perfect circle in real life either.